# Error when posting XML to REST service

Tags: php, rest, post, curl

I am trying to post XML data to SmashFly using cURL but I keep getting this error:

The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'

I've tried several different variation of this line:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('contentType:text/xml'));
but I always get the "message format was raw"

Here is the complete posting code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('contentType:text/xml'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is per the documentation:

This  REST method expects an HTTP POST to the REST URL provided. The post “contentType” should 
be set to “text/xml"

Any ideas on what I'm missing?